# How can I prevent android app from opening files in external apps?

Tags: android, google-docs

I have a native android app. I show a link to the Word file in a text area. When I tap it, my app switches to Google Docs and shows message that it is not possible to open the document. I would like to switch this behaviour and just allow users to download the file without switching to an external app. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsynTask` for download file from web like below:

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String fileName="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String fileUrl;   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
        fileUrl = strings[0];
          // -> maven.pdf
        fileName = strings[1];
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/Android/data/com.mymdsmanager";
        File dir = new File(extStorageDirectory);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File pdfFile = new File(dir, fileName);

        try{
            pdfFile.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (!fileName.equals(""))
            openMail(fileName); // here i want to open file in mail you can write your own code as per your requirements

    }
}
public void openMail(String tableName){
    String[] mailto = {MyApplication.getEmailId()};
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/Android/data/com.mymdsmanager";
    File pdfFile = new File(path , tableName);
    Log.d("File", "openMail: " + pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MDS Manager Data - "+tableName);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is the MDS Manager data export that you requested.");
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**FileDownloader.java**

```
public class FileDownloader {
    private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally make call of `DownloadFile()` method like below:

```
new DownloadFile().execute(link, table_name+".pdf");
```

I hope this may help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Download Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads. It takes care of downloading in the background, retrying downloads after any failures etc. It is recommended to use DownloadManager for any long running HTTP downloads.

```
 public static void downloadFile(Context context, String url, String title, String description)    {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    if(title != null)
        request.setTitle(title);
    if(description != null)
        request.setDescription(description);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title);

    // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

You can have the above method in a Util class, and it can be called from any activity where you need to make the download from by passing the Context. Title and description can also be passed into the method for more customized notifications.

You could do something like -

```
viewThatHoldsTheLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //call download File
            downloadFile(mContext, theWordDocUrl, "Abc Document", "Here is your abc document");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your suggestions. They gave me a clue where to look at in my app. It turned out that the directory to which I was downloading files was unreachable by a user. I had to change it to Downloads directory and suddenly all started to work.